# PHP Login Form - Not Seeing mySQL Rows

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, authentication

Simple Question: Trying to create a php login form. My database is connected successfully. I currently have 1 table row in mySQL. So why is my $numrow variable echoing 0/ Why is my username in my database not being recognized? What am I missing? Please, help. Not a php expert.

Thanks!

```
<?php
include 'includes/top.php';
?>

<?php 
error_reporting(0);

session_start();



    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "hostname", "password") or die ("Couldn't connect!");

    mysql_select_db("djones33") or die ("Couldn't find db!");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tm_user WHERE username='$username'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    echo $numrows;

    if ($numrows!=0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $db_username = $row['username'];
            $db_password = $row['password'];    
        }}

        if (isset($_POST["username"])) { 
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    //they did, so now, has the username AND password been entered? 
    if ((isset($_POST["username"])) && (isset($_POST["password"]))){ 
        //they have, now, is the username correct?
        if ($_POST["username"]!=$db_username && $_POST["username"]!=""){
            $uerror="<p class='error'>* The username you entered is not correct.</p>";
            //echo "$uerror";   
        } else {
            echo "";
          }
         //now, is the password correct?
        if ($_POST["password"]!=$db_password && $_POST["password"]!=""){
            $perror="<p class='error'>* The password you entered is not correct.";
            //echo "$perror";   
        } else {
            echo "";
          }
        //they haven't entered a username, so...  
        if ($_POST["username"]=="") {
            $emptyu="<p class='error'>* You must enter a username.</p>";
            //echo $emptyu; 
        }
        //they haven't entered a username, so...
        if ($_POST["password"]=="") {
            $emptyp="<p class='error'>* You must enter a password.</p>";
            //echo $emptyu; 
        }
        //if the username and password are correct, give them the welcome page!
        if ($_POST["username"]==$db_username && $_POST["password"]==$db_password) {
            echo "";
            $_SESSION['username']=$db_username;
            //$welcome = "Welcome, ".$user. "! You have successfully logged in.";

        }   
    } 
}
?>
    <h2><span class="green_title">Welcome</span><br><span class="title_size">to YOUR.to-do!</span></h2>

    <section id="login_area">

        <div id="login_title">
            <p>Login</p>
        </div>

        <div id="form_area">
            <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <?php echo $uerror; echo $emptyu;?>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" id="username"/><br/>
            <?php echo $perror; echo $emptyp;?>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password"/><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" class="button"/>
            </form>
        </div>  

    </section>

    <footer>
        <p>New user? | <a href="register.php">Register</a></p>
    </footer>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because, this `if (isset($_POST["username"])) { $username = $_POST["username"];` is in the wrong place. You're putting the wagon before the horse, as it were. The wagon being `$query = mysql_query(...`

Comment: Nice injection vulnerability you have going on there. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Wait, are you storing plaintext passwords too? Don't do that. Ever. Use a decent hashing algorithm (NOT md5).

Comment: @TheBlueDog It was just for giving OP a better understanding about SQL injection due to mysql_ functions...Why did you downvoted? you have no rights so far...and I have also deleted the comment.

Comment: @TheBlueDog It was right for the question asked there...I will not delete my answer on that post..I have already deleted my comment here as I said...Reverse your downvote.

Comment: @TheBlueDog and if you know there is vulnerability to my answer, then edit my answer...ok? I don't understand if it was right or wrong there(first see the question there).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PHP's built-in [Password Hashing Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) and the [PDOStatement Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). When your users register be sure to use password_hash() on the passwords they submit before saving them in your database. And when you query your database use PDOStatements and bound parameters to keep your site safe from SQL injection attacks.

Your log in script should look something like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Database_Name', 'Username', 'Password');
$ps = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tm_user WHERE username = (:username)");
$ps->bindParam(":username", $_POST["username"]);
$ps->execute();
$result = $ps->fetch(); // $result is an array representing the row in tm_user with the submitted username

if(count($result) === 0)
{
    // username not found
}
else if(password_verify($_POST["password"], $result["password"]) === false)
{
    // password is incorrect
}
else if(password_verify($_POST["password"], $result["password"]) === true)
{
    // give them the welcome page!
}
```

Remember: password_verify() will only work if you used password_hash() on the password before storing it in the database.